# Using Iframe in big web applications?

Tags: php, jquery, web-applications, iframe

I am building my own application for the past 1 year and i am looking to improve it further. I research alot of applications and found out that big applications (by Google), for e.g. analytics uses iframe.

I am thinking of implementing iframe into my web application and i am looking for insights from experienced developers.

One of the biggest benefiti think is: Load faster. in this case the whole page is not loaded. Improved time response -> am i right?

I think also thinking of ajaxifying one (main) container but i think iframe will be better in this case.

Advice appreciated

Comment: you can use fancybox for iframe http://zfranciscus.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/managing-iframe-using-fancybox/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link. will check it out. I am more of looking for ideas on the design aspect - especially the performance part.

Comment: this cant be answered, it highly depends on what information you want to display how in your application, one time ajax is better, the next time iframe is better.

Comment: here is some links related to google iframe you said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151701/running-google-analytics-in-iframe   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423128/google-analytics-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Big Applications(Google) in multiple servers,domains,systems . for example : in this case Google applications(cross GMail,GPlus,etc) use `IFrame` for User Authentication . but if your application is single system, JSON,Cache-Control could be more performance(Low Latency)